# Eliminate negative zero in axes ticks

Tags: matlab, plot

I have found that under some circumstances MATLAB will print negative -0.0 as an axis tick. How can I eliminate this?

Problem code

```
y = linspace(-.4,.3,100);
plot(y)
ax = gca();
ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%.1f'`
```

This code produces a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWedp.png) where instead of zero tick reading '0.0' it reads '-0.0'.

I think the key here is that the interval between the maximum and minimum of the Y axis cannot be represented exactly as a float, so the 'zero' tick is actually located at -5.6e-17. You can see this if instead use the formatting `ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%.1e'`

For picky formatting reason, I really prefer that all my axis ticks have the same number of digits (i.e. -0.1, 0.0, 0.1 rather than -0.1, 0, 0.1). Is there any way to eliminate the negative zero in this formatting?

Using MATLAB2017a on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose floating point format, you get what you wanted with [floating point accuracy issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). You can define `y = linspace(-.4,.3,100)+eps;` to solve it...

Comment: Thanks, this works! In the case of my actual problem (which involved using the `axis` command), it can similarly be solved by changing, for example, `axis([0 100 -0.4 0.3])` to `axis([0 100 -0.4 0.3+eps])`

Comment: Also I've submitted a bug report to Mathworks for this issue and the workaround.